# Switching to different DataTable page when input change in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, dt

Basically, I want the output DataTable to **switch to the page** that has the values matching with the Input selection value (`radioButtons`). I know I can do a simple filter but that would remove all the other rows that do not match the criteria which I do not want.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  h3("The mtcars data"),
  fluidRow(column(2,
                  offset = 1,
                  radioButtons("valSel", strong("Gear"),
                               inline = TRUE,
                               choices = c("3", "4", "5"),
                               selected = "3")),
           fluidRow(column(10,
                           offset = 1,
                           dataTableOutput("mytable")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    mtcars[mtcars$gear == input$valSel, ]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure how would that work. The datatable shows 10 entries, but this number does not match the number of cases in each value of gear. However, this Q&A has an application somewhat similar to your issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56807006/shiny-dt-how-to-type-page-number-manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom `js` function and switch to the desired page.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- basicPage(
  h3("The mtcars data"),
  fluidRow(column(2,
                  offset = 1,
                  radioButtons("valSel", strong("Gear"),
                               inline = TRUE,
                               choices = c("3", "4", "5"),
                               selected = "3")),
           fluidRow(column(10,
                           offset = 1, # verbatimTextOutput("t1"),
                           DTOutput("mytable")))
  ),
  tags$script(HTML(
    "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('pager',function(page) {
      $('#'+'mytable').find('table').DataTable().page(page).draw(false);
    })"
  ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  mydf <- reactive({
    mtcars %>% mutate(rowid = row_number())
  })

  subdf <- reactive({
    req(mydf())
    mydf()[mydf()$gear == input$valSel, ]
  })
  output$t1 <- renderPrint({ceiling(min(subdf()$rowid)/10)})

  output$mytable = renderDT({
    n <- length(names(mydf())) ## to remove rowid
    mydf()[,-n]
  })

  observeEvent(input$valSel,{

    page <- ceiling(min(subdf()$rowid)/10) ## assumes 10 rows are displayed per page (default); if different, replace 10 by the number of rows displayed per page
    
    session$sendCustomMessage("pager",page-1)

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is probably a way to go for now

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear how you would identify the page where particular values are given they may contain different numbers of rows.

One alternative to setting the page would be to use the `factor` data type to reorder the categories depending on the radio button input, which would simply bring the category of interest to the top of the data frame being passed to `renderDatatable`:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  h3("The mtcars data"),
  fluidRow(column(2,
                  offset = 1,
                  radioButtons("valSel", strong("Gear"),
                               inline = TRUE,
                               choices = c("3", "4", "5"),
                               selected = "3")),
           fluidRow(column(10,
                           offset = 1,
                           dataTableOutput("mytable")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  df <- reactive({
    gear_vals <- unique(as.character(mtcars$gear))
    mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear, 
                          levels = c(input$valSel, 
                                     gear_vals[input$valSel != gear_vals]))
    mtcars[order(mtcars$gear),]
  })
  
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    df()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks! My reasoning was that: we might know the page number for each `gear` in advance (not sure if it's possible with `DT`). So before any selection takes place, reset the table back to its original form, then go to that page.